# How to implement MongoDB transactions in a Node.js Express REST API project using the repository pattern?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, transactions, repository-pattern

I am working on a Node.js Express REST API project that follows the repository pattern for data access. I would like to implement MongoDB transactions in this project. However, I'm unsure about how to integrate transactions into the existing codebase and which layer would be best suited for implementing transactions.

What I've tried:
I have already set up the project with the repository pattern, where each repository handles the data access for a specific entity. However, I'm not sure how to incorporate MongoDB transactions into this pattern.

Expected outcome:
I need to know which layer (e.g., controller, service, repository) is best for implementing transactions and how to modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.